# Increase map max zoom level

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is it possible to increase map max zoom level?  By default it is 18, but I need something around 25-30.
Using newest React-Leaflet, `MaxNativeZoom` do nothing.

Example code:

```
<Map center={[55, 55]} zoom={18} maxNativeZoom={30}>
  <TileLayer
    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
  <FeatureGroup>
    <EditControl position="topright" onCreated={this.onCreated} />
  </FeatureGroup>
  {this.state.positions.map((position) => (
    <Marker position={[position.lat, position.lng]}></Marker>
  ))}
</Map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `maxZoom` to your map.

```
<Map center={[55, 55]} zoom={18} maxZoom={30}>
```